# Comparing treatment means with lots of zeros

Tags: data-transformation, normality-assumption, univariate, zero-inflation

I am trying to compare the means of two treatments on a continuous variable with a lot of zeros in it.  I've tried a log(n+1) transformation but that did not get me to a normal distribution.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are they zero? Is it because of limitations on instrumentation in measuring small quantities, or are they real zeros? What does the distribution look like with $\log(y+1)$? (And why do you write $n$ as the response variable? By notational convention, seems like you have a count, not a continuous measurement.

Answer (score 2):

*No* transformation will separate values that are the same.

If half your original values are 0 (say), then half your values will be equal to whatever you transform 0 to. They'll stick together no matter which way you choose to torture them.

(Well, I guess you could arguably replace them by random numbers, but that's not what people generally interpret 'transformation' to include, and it would rarely be helpful to do that.)

You can't "fix" a large point-mass, it stubbornly remains a large point-mass no matter how much you beg it to change its ways.

Much better to deal with your actual situation than try to smoosh this particular square peg into that particular round hole.

If your data are otherwise continuous, there are zero-inflated continuous models that may be suitable. If they're discrete (like counts, for example), you should usually deal with them as counts (and perhaps, may still require a zero-inflated model).